# How Can I Make a Chuck Berry Inspired Piece?

Tags: theory, technique, styles, rock-n-roll

I'm thinking about making an unofficial Club Penguin Music Jam song for the Pizza Parlor, and I want to make it inspired by Chuck Berry, the king of Rock and Roll. What can I do to achieve the Chuck Berry influence?
[image]

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you’re looking for. My first thought is to suggest learning to play a lot of or all of Chuck Berry’s songs and analyzing his work to see what is similar about all his songs and what makes them different from other songs.